# Cannot start mongod service because of data folder not found

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I created the folder `/var/lib/mongodb/data/db` with `sudo`.

I changed in the `.conf` file to the following: `dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb/data/db` as it seems to be the default that Mongo db uses, right?

So I try `sudo mongod` and I still get

`exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating`

I try `sudo service mongod start` and I get log error:

`Unable to create/open lock file: /var/lib/mongodb/data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?`

The user permissions for `/var/lib/mongodb/data/db` for the `mongodb` user are as follows: `drwxr-xr-x mongodb mongodb mongodb` (the same as for `root`)

I run `ps aux | grep mongodb` on my user and there is one process running, but I cannot stop it. It starts automatically with the OS. What is going on? Why can't I setup the damn default db data path?!

Comment: Instead of giving ~/develoeper... Can you try giving the full path like /home/<user>/developer... ?

Comment: @LalitAgarwal , still not working.

Comment: Ok. So, can you also check which user is running the service.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the problem is for the `~` before your path.
If you run mongodb as a service, the user who run mongoDB is `mongodb`.

If you want to run mongod as a service, dont't use home directory shortcut but full path of db directory.

I recommand you to save mongoDB database in the `/var` or `/opt` folder. Not in /home folder and you should be sure the user right is `mongodb`.

The mongodb service on Ubuntu used the `/etc/mongod.conf`. You should modify the `dbPath` config if you used the previous config format (in ubuntu, by default, it's the previous format).

To stop the service start automatically with ubuntu, you should use `sudo service mongod stop`.

In your problem, i think it's not the mongod service is run right ? In that case you should find the startup programs. What version of ubuntu and mongodb used you ? If you used the ubuntu 2.6, normally, it's startup with `upstart` service. See the config file in `/etc/init/mongod.conf`